# How to define expected answers in a multiple choices question in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner to Python and Pandas. I'm just learning how to use them to apply them to my thesis.

As part of my thesis, I have conducted intercept surveys with people on the street, where I asked them to evaluate an urban space on a scale from 1-5.

When I generated a profile report in Pandas, I noticed that the questions where the respondents didn't answer with all available answers (i.e. from 1-5) gave data that the profile report interpreted as categorical values.

How do I make the profile report "anticipate" that there will be values that won't be chosen by the respondents, and that should still be included in the analysis?

Below are the columns that are available in my dataframe:

```
habitation               category
visit_freq               category
place_affinity            float64
place_identity            float64
place_relatibility        float64
place_belonging           float64
sound_distinctiveness     float64
traffic_noise             float64
industry_noise            float64
ind_noise                 float64
crowds_noise              float64
natural_noise             float64
sound_pleasant            float64
sound_vibrant             float64
sound_eventful            float64
sound_chaotic             float64
sound_annoying            float64
sound_monotonous          float64
sound_uneventful          float64
sound_calm                float64
sound_appropriateness     float64
dtype: object
```

All float64 values should be seen as numerical values in the profiling report, with responses ranging from 1-5. The questions with answer values that are "missing" are seen as categorical, not numerical.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can replace `null` values with 0 with `df[COLUMN_NAME].fillna(0)`. By the way, sharing a reproducible sample of your dataset would help us to solve your problem more quickly.

Comment: You can create a [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) column with categories: NoResponse, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: @VladimirFokow I don't want to create a categorical column, as that doesn't allow for numerical column analysis in the profile report, which I'm interested in.